# Remove NOT duplicates value from list

Tags: python, arrays, list, duplicates

The scenario is this something like this:

After joining several lists using:

```
list1 = ["A","B"]
list2 = ["A","B","C"]
list3 = ["C","D","E"]

mainlist = list1 + list2 + list3
mainlist.sort()
```

mainlist now looks like that:

```
mainlist = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E']
```

I would like to remove anything that is not a duplicate value. If the value in question is already present in the list it must not be touched and while if it is present only once in the mainlist I would like to delete it.

I tried to use this approach but seems something isn't working:

```
for i in mainlist:
    if mainlist.count(i) <= 1:
        mainlist.remove(i)
    else:
        continue
```

but what I return is a list that looks like the following:

```
mainlist = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'E'] #value "D" is not anymore present. Why?
```

What i would like to return is a list like that:

```
mainlist = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'] #All values NOT duplicates have been deleted
```

I can delete the duplicates with the below code:

```
for i in mainlist:
    if mainlist.count(i) > 1:
        mainlist.remove(i)
    else:
        continue
```

and then as a final result:

```
mainlist = ['A','B','C']
```

But the real question is: how can I delete the non-duplicates in a list?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete unique elements from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26870699/delete-unique-elements-from-a-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in you operating on the while iterating over it. After removing the `"D"` the loops stops because there are no more elements in the list as the `"E"` at index 6.

Create a copy of the list and only operate on that list:

```py
new_list = list(mainlist)
for i in mainlist:
    if mainlist.count(i) <= 1:
        new_list.remove(i)
    else:
        continue
```

Answer (score 4):

You can find duplicates like this:

```
duplicates = [item for item in mainlist if mainlist.count(item) > 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the list elements. Use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to keep only the elements that occur more than once. Note that the list does not have to be sorted.

```
from collections import Counter
list1 = ["A","B"]
list2 = ["A","B","C"]
list3 = ["C","D","E"]
mainlist = list1 + list2 + list3

cnt = Counter(mainlist)
print(cnt)
# Counter({'A': 2, 'B': 2, 'C': 2, 'D': 1, 'E': 1})

dups = [x for x in mainlist if cnt[x] > 1]
print(dups)
# ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C']
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, using `numpy`:

```py
u, c = np.unique(mainlist, return_counts=True)
out = np.repeat(u[c > 1], c[c > 1])
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['A' 'A' 'B' 'B' 'C' 'C']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collections.Counter()` to keep track of the frequencies of each item:

```py
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(mainlist)
[item for item in mainlist if counts[item] > 1]
```

This outputs:

```py
['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to output only a list of duplicate elements in your lists, you can use sets and a comprehension to keep only the duplicates.

```py
list1 = ["A","B"]
list2 = ["A","B","C"]
list3 = ["C","D","E"]

fulllist = list1 + list2 + list3
fullset = set(list1) | set(list2) | set(list3)

dups = [x for x in fullset if fulllist.count(x) > 1]

print(dups)  # ['A', 'C', 'B']
```